# Drupal Commerce Offsite Payments sending multiple emails

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

Hi I have a Drupal 7 site running with Drupal Commerce. There is a events/booking calendar that has offsite payment options for each event.

Whenever the offsite payment email is sent it is sending the same email multiple times, not once as needed but up to five times. The purchaser receives the email once as needed, but the admin gets the same email five times which will cause confusion etc....

Has anyone had this problem?? Know of a fix as to why Drupal (Commerce) is doing this??

Comment: All of the additional emails are sent as forwarded if that helps

Comment: I've troubleshooted the issue, it's not the said module, neither the PHP Mailer SMTP I'm using, but Drupal Rules. I'm trying to obtain the logs for this, but the sites keeps maxing out for some reason. The rule is triggering 'Send Email' and for some reason sending multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable rules debug mode , you can find the all the rules that fire on each event, as I understand your rules firing 5 times . You have to set proper condition when exact the rule will fire. Thanks

Comment: The problem I'm having now is when I enable the offsite payment rule I'm getting 504's so it won't even process it let alone debug why there are multiple emails/triggers firing.

Comment: Ok I have things working and the message is only sending twice once at the payment offline option at the end of the process when it should and once at checkout when it shouldn't. I've added the event to the rule - Select available payment methods for an order which is exactly when I want the rule to fire. Is there any way to prevent the first triggering??

Comment: Ok so I used WebForms hooked into Product SKU for Offline Payments bypassing the whole Commerce process. Online purchasing via Commerce Process.

Comment: There was no clear way emails were firing for the Commerce Process even though at no point I had the rule within that set. Totally unintuitive.

Comment: Ideally it should fire after order process complete. you can give me quick access to your admin.

Comment: Thanks Sunil Dev is completed anyway using WebForms as an offline option.